# How to add left and right margins to UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have been trying to search for a solution to add spacing between the border of my UITableViewCells and the left and right sides of the view, but the answers I have found so far do not actually affect the spacing between the borders and the view. I've tried a few stuff, but the most common answer was to use code like this:

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20)
```

I added this to viewDidLoad but it does nothing other than allow the tableView to also be scrolled horizontally.

Comment: So the UITableViewCell has a UIView. Just put another UIView in the UIView and you can assign left and right anchorpoints 20?

Comment: @Vollan I added a subview to cell.contentView, I have two labels in my contentview. Do I add these labels to the subview, then do the cell customizations (borderColor, radius) to the subview? The labels are part of a custom class for the cells.

Comment: It depends on what you wish to achieve. I never use the contentView and always use the UIView. But if you want to edit the layer of the cell it should be on the directly on the cell itself and all your labels as such should be in the UIView that is in the subview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked when I added this code to my cell's class.

```
override var frame: CGRect {
        get {
            return super.frame
        }
        set {
            var frame = newValue
            frame.origin.x += 5
            frame.size.width -= 2 * 5

            super.frame = frame
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is working..